# Go to next block if there is no blank cells in the selected range

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following auto generated code to look for 0 s in a selected column range (E), replace it with a blank and then search for blanks in that column and delete the records by row.

```
Cells.Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder _
:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

I run this on different ranges that might or might not have 0's in it. Problem is if it doesn't, the entire selected E column gets deleted. 
When i do this manually, i get an error message saying  "No Cells Were Found". I don't get this when i run the macro. I turn off alerts later in the macro but not before i run this block.

Can i get suggestions on how to handle this error? If the selected range doesn't have zeros, ignore the next line of code or something?

Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A half haphazardly way:

```
On Error Resume Next
'your one line code goes here'
On Error Goto 0
'the rest of your code goes here
```

Full code snippet to make it work, plus try not to use select.

```
Dim WorkingRange As Range
Set WorkingRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("E:E")

On Error Resume Next
WorkingRange.Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
WorkingRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion. 
I used On Error GoTo <Lable> temporally. What's the benefit of using your second suggestion as opposed to my one?

Comment: none, as far as I know, don't forget to reset your error handler, or on all errors the macro will jump to the label. I usually use labels in error handling when I have a section at the end of a macro handling all sorts of possible errors, for specific case when I am too lazy to create proper error handlers I usually do the above, just don't forget to add on error goto 0

Comment: Don't you need the On Error around the SpecialCells line as that will error if there are no blanks?

Comment: @SJR yes. That's what i did but i wanted to know if there is a better way. :)